# rush config errors: not an absolute directory name

Tags: unix-shell

Migrating from rssh to rush...

I can't figure out what it means by `not an absolute directory name`. see logs below:

```
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user upload by (uid=0)
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: debug level set to 3
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:5: 
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:6: #
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:7: # Default settings
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:8: #
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:9: 
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:10: rule default
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:11: acct on
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:12: limits t10r20
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:13: umask 002
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:14: env - USER LOGNAME HOME PATH
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:15: #
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:16: # Uncomment this to activate the notification subsystem:
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:17: # (Also install 'rush-notifier' or a similar script.)
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:18: #
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:19: #post-socket inet://localhost
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:20: #
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:21: fall-through
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:22: 
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:23: ######################
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:24: # File moving services
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:25: ######################
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:26: 
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:27: # Scp requests: only putting, no fetching.
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:28: #
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:29: # The server host needs the paths
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:30: #
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:31: #   /srv/rush/srv/incoming/{alpha,ftp}
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:32: #
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:33: # and that they be writable! A specific
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:34: # group can be assigned to all users
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:35: # expected to gain access via GNU rush.
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:36: 
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:37: rule scp-to
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:38: command ^scp (-v )?-t( --)?
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:39: set[0] /usr/bin/scp
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:40: chroot "/data/upload"
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:40: not an absolute directory name
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:41: chdir "/"
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: /etc/rush.rc:41: not an absolute directory name
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: Finished parsing /etc/rush.rc
Aug 31 14:07:24 secmgrprd04 rush[3904968]: errors parsing config file
```

I actually copied the example from the documentation which had `chroot "~"` and I changed it to an absolute path and still got the same error.

Ubuntu 20.04, installed by apt, Version: 1.8+dfsg-1.1

baffled!

Comment: as stated in the lines above, path must be absolutely meant chroot "/data/upload/"

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

```
   chroot <DIR>
          Change the root directory to DIR.  This directory  will  be  used  for  file  names
          beginning  with  /.   A  tilde at the start of DIR is replaced with the user's home
          directory.

   chdir <DIR>
          Change to the directory DIR.  The argument is  subject  to  tilde-expansion  as  in
          chroot,  above.   If  both  chdir and chroot are specified, then chroot is executed
          first.
```

Now I guess either dir is not exists or permissions are missing. To check which parameter causing issue add `debug 3` line to your config.